How to make two nodes of same width? minimum width not working as expected!
I have to make rectangle "Data Members" of same width as the rectangle "Data Methods". I tried changing "minimum width" tag but is not affecting anything. How can I make the two rectangles of same size?
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}% For the example only, any class will do
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}% To get more advances positioning options
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}% To get more arrow heads
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
    
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            s1/.style       ={rectangle, draw=cyan!70, fill=red!10, minimum size=30, minimum width=40},
            s3/.style       ={rectangle, draw=teal!70, fill=teal!10, minimum width = 200, behind path}, 
]
            \node[s1]       (n1)    
            {
                \begin {tabular} {l}
                    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\underline{\ttfamily{Data Members}}}     \\
                    \ttfamily{aaa1}     \\
                    \ttfamily{aaa2}
                \end{tabular}
            }
        
            node[s1]        (n2)    [below=0.1cm of n1]
            {
                \begin {tabular} {l}
                    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\underline{\ttfamily{Data Methods}}}     \\
                    \ttfamily{bbb1}     \\
                    \ttfamily{bbbcccdddeeefffggghhhiiijjj2}     \\
                \end{tabular}
            }
    
            node[s3]        (n3)    [fit=(n1) (n2)]     {};
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Please extend your sniplet to a full bit minimal example others can copy and test as is. As a sniplet is is also not clear which tikz libraries are needed to be loaded for this to compile.

Richt: try a few semicola ...

This code is working in my TexStudio setup.

Your minimum width is to low. If you use, e.g., minimum width=180 in s1/.style both nodes have the same width. But maybe this is an XY problem, something like: how to use multi-line text in nodes. BTW: Package tcolorbox also may be useful for such boxes.

Hm, it will work, because you don't follow the path-pattern \ something ; ... in fact you have one path putting 3 nodes ... though it's possible, the better was yould be to use 3 statements \node ... ;   ... // Remember me the next time your Tikz code goes wild ...

minimum width makes a node at least that wide. If the content is wider, the node may be wider. If you want to ensure the same width, use text width=<width> rather than minimum width=<width> and then align=left or center or whatever you wish.
But note that if you then put something wider into a tabular column l, it will simply protrude outside the node because it can't be broken. There is no reason to use a tabular here with only one column. Just use
\node[s1]        (n2)    [below=0.1cm of n1]
{\underline{\ttfamily{Data Methods}}\\
        \ttfamily{bbb1}\\
        \ttfamily{bbbcccdddeeefffggghhhiiijjj2}};

However, to work, TeX must be able to break the lines, too. So some random string of letters won't work because there's nowhere for a line to break. Assuming your real content includes multiple words, however, it will work.
node[s1]        (n2)    [below=0.1cm of n1]
{%
        \underline{\ttfamily{Data Methods}}\\
        \ttfamily{bbb1}\\
        \ttfamily{bbbcccdddeee fffggghhh iiijjj2}%
}

\ttfamily doesn't take an argument. It is a switch. You can just add font=\ttfamily to the definition of s1. Or use \texttt{<text>} if you want an argument.
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}% For the example only, any class will do
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}% To get more advances positioning options
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}% To get more arrow heads
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  s1/.style       ={rectangle, draw=cyan!70, fill=red!10, minimum size=30, text width=65,font=\ttfamily},
  s3/.style       ={rectangle, draw=teal!70, fill=teal!10, minimum width = 200, behind path,font=\ttfamily}, 
  ]
  \node[s1]       (n1)    
  {\underline{Data Members}\\
    aaa1\\
    aaa2%
  }
  
  node[s1]        (n2)    [below=0.1cm of n1]
  {%
    \underline{Data Methods}\\
    bbb1\\
    bbbcccdddeee fffggghhh iiijjj2%
  }
  
  node[s3]        (n3)    [fit=(n1) (n2)]     {};
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Experimental image:


It's easier to make this kind of box using the tcolorbox package, which is designed for this purpose and written with tikz.
In this case, I'm using the raster library to create boxes of the same dimensions.
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}% To get more advances positioning options
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}% To get more arrow heads
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\begin{document}


\begin{tcboxedraster}[raster columns=1,
    size=small,
    sharp corners,
    raster width=6cm,
    colframe=cyan!70,
    colback=red!10,
    colbacktitle=red!50!white,
    title={}
    ]
{sharp corners,colframe=teal!70,colback=teal!10,width=7cm,}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\underline{\ttfamily{Data Members}}\\
    \ttfamily{aaa1}     \\
    \ttfamily{aaa2}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\underline{\ttfamily{Data Methods}}\\
    \ttfamily{aaa1}\\
    \ttfamily{aaa2}item Three\\
    \ttfamily{bbb1}     \\
    \ttfamily{bbbcccdddeeefffggghhhiiijjj2}   
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{tcboxedraster}

\end{document}


